# Firebase limit deprecated, how to use limitToLast or limitToFirst?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I'm getting this console message in my firebase application:
"FIREBASE WARNING: Query.limit() being deprecated. Please use Query.limitToFirst() or Query.limitToLast() instead."

But when I change from:

```
fbutil.syncArray('messages', {limit: 10, endAt: null});
```

To this:

```
fbutil.syncArray('messages', {limitToLast: 10, endAt: null});
```

I get all the messages.

Btw, I'm using the angularfire-seed, and I have updated the firebase scripts to the latest ("firebase": "~2.2.x", "angularfire": "~0.9.x",).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, I found the "problem".
I had to add the properties to the syncData function in the firabase.utils.js file.

```
angular.forEach(['limitToFirst', 'limitToLast', 'startAt', 'endAt'], function(k) {...}
```